# Finding Horizontal Tangents - Extraneous Solution

Tags: calculus

In a tutorial problem, we are asked to find the horizontal and vertical tangents of $$ x(x+2)^{3/5}$$

I'm fine getting the vertical tangent of $x = -2$ by finding the values of $x$ such that the limit equals infinity (does not exist) since it is continuous, but when I algebraically solve for the horizontal tangent, I get that there are horizontal tangents when both $x = -1.25$ (checked the answer, is correct) and $x = -2$ (which is incorrect).

How should I handle the emergence of this extraneous solution?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x(x+2)^{\frac{3}{5}}$$
$$f'(x)=(x+2)^{\frac{3}{5}}+\frac{3}{5}x(x+2)^{-\frac{2}{5}}$$

Multiply nominator and denominator by $(x+2)^{\frac{2}{5}}$ Then:

$$f'(x)=\frac{x+2+\frac{3}{5}x}{(x+2)^{\frac{2}{5}}}$$ which equals zero when $x=-1.25$

Comment: Imre, and, what about $x=-2$?

Comment: @zoli At $x=-2$ the derivative is not defined

Comment: @zoli but the limit of the derivative around $x=-2$ goes to minus $\infty$ so there will be a vertical asymptote

Answer (score 0):

Slope is zero at horizontal tangent.

Slope is $\infty $ at vertical tangent.